# What is the difference between "using std::string" and "#include <string>"

Tags: c++, string, include, using

I am newly learning C++, I do not really understand the difference between putting `using std::string` vs `#include <string>` at the top of my main file.

I seem to be able to define strings without having `#include <string>` here:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s = "hi";
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to run without issue, so why would I have `#include <string>`?

Comment: It works because `#include <iostream>` has in it `#include <string>`.  You can't count on this.  If you wan to use `std::string`, you must `#include <string>`

Comment: The `#include <iostream>` on your compiler also does a `#include <string>`.  So your program has an indirect dependency.  Doesn't compile on my compiler.

Comment: It isn't, I've removed that now, it was one of the header files I was using to test things

Comment: I think @NathanOliver has answered my question, I didn't realise that iostream included string

Comment: C++ allows one standard header file to include another. So <iostream> might implicitly include <string>. But on another compiler that might not be true. So when you use `std::string` you should `#include <string>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `<string>` header to use `std::string`.

Adding `using std::string;` allows you to use it without the `std::` namespace qualifier.

If you include a header that includes `<string>` you may not have to do so explicitly. However, it is bad practice to count on this, and well-written headers include guards against multiple inclusion, so assuming you're using well-written header files, there is no harm in including a header that was included via a previous include.